# Cassandra Cluster Replication- Existing Node & Existing Data

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cassandra

We have one requirement where we need to replicate Cassandra Cluster with existing nodes and existing data in it. Approx 2.5 TB of data is on Azure and 3.5 TB on AWS. We need to pull the remaining data from AWS to Azure. Your Kind Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options here.

You can connect the two using GPFS - stand up a DC in Azure replicate across remove the old DC.

You could unload the data via the Cassandra loader.  https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader

You could take a snapshot and then stream the data to the new cluster via sstableloader.

It's hard to give a complete answer - it would depend on so many factors.  The above should get you started at least.